# Безопасно ли приведение типа Set к List?

Tags: java

Компилятор не жалуется абсолютно, но все же интересно.

Comment: Свои примеры кода добавьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, они в разных ветвях наследования от `Collection` ни одна стандартная реализация `List` не наследует `Set`. И если вы используете одну из этих реализаций в рантайме вы получите `ClasslCastException`. Только в случае, если ваша коллекция реализует оба этих интерфейса - приведение типа сработает.

[image: collections]